# Microsoft Access Insert into

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that looks up information in a form and returns data.  When I run it as a select query it returns the correct information.  However when I try to turn in into an update query it inserts an ID instead to the data.  I am not understanding why this is changing.

SELECT query:

```
SELECT Templates.Shift, Templates.Supervisor, 
       forms.[Enter Production].[production Date] AS Expr1, 
       Templates.[Work Center] 
FROM Templates 
WHERE (((Templates.Shift)=[Forms]![Enter Production]![Production Shift]) 
AND ((Templates.Supervisor)=[Forms]![Enter Production]![Supervisor]));
```

INSERT INTO query:

```
INSERT INTO Production ( Shift, Supervisor, [Date], [Work Center] ) 
SELECT Templates.Shift, Templates.Supervisor, 
       forms.[Enter Production].[production Date] AS Expr1, 
       Templates.[Work Center] 
FROM Templates 
WHERE (((Templates.Shift)=[Forms]![Enter Production]![Production Shift])
AND ((Templates.Supervisor)=[Forms]![Enter Production]![Supervisor]));
```

Comment: We cannot guess what SQL code your query contains ...

Comment: Please post your queries (both the SELECT and UPDATE) and we can try to debug it.  Without your actual query syntax, this question is unanswerable and will be closed.

Comment: SELECT Templates.Shift, Templates.Supervisor, forms.[Enter Production].[production Date] AS Expr1, Templates.[Work Center]
FROM Templates
WHERE (((Templates.Shift)=[Forms]![Enter Production]![Production Shift]) AND ((Templates.Supervisor)=[Forms]![Enter Production]![Supervisor]));

Comment: INSERT INTO Production ( Shift, Supervisor, [Date], [Work Center] )
SELECT Templates.Shift, Templates.Supervisor, forms.[Enter Production].[production Date] AS Expr1, Templates.[Work Center]
FROM Templates
WHERE (((Templates.Shift)=[Forms]![Enter Production]![Production Shift]) AND ((Templates.Supervisor)=[Forms]![Enter Production]![Supervisor]));

Comment: These are my 2 queries the select reports out the [work center] name and the insert reports back the ID #

Comment: Is Templates.[Work Center] a text-type data? Or does it come from another table with an associated Work Centre ID? Is that the ID that is getting inserted?

Comment: The work center comes from the work centers table and the work centers table is the one I get the id from instead of the machine name.